# SharedPreferences doing weird things

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I want to save the users choice of theme using `sharedPreferences` every time they hit the button "Save" but there is something that I clearly doing wrong but I can't see it.

My problem is, without the `sharedPreferences` stuff my application changes themes the way i want and there is no problem on it. But when I apply the `sharedPreferences` things it stops changing themes, and it's not saving neither.

I put some comments to help understand what and where I'm trying to accomplish.

Here is my settings class:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

public static final String PREF_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
public static int newTheme;
public final static int THEME_DARK = R.style.DarkTheme;
public final static int THEME_LIGHT = R.style.LightTheme;
public final static int THEME_COLORS = R.style.ColorsTheme;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Here is where I'm supposed to check the sharedPreferences then
    // Set the theme option newTheme with the users last choice, 
            // and if there is
    // a choice set the theme.
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    newTheme = settings.getInt("themeCustom", 0);   

     if(newTheme == THEME_DARK) {
        setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme);

    } else if(newTheme == THEME_LIGHT){
        setTheme(R.style.LightTheme);
    } else if(newTheme == THEME_COLORS) {
        setTheme(R.style.ColorsTheme);
    } else { 
    // Utils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
     }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button4).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button5).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button6).setOnClickListener(this);
}   
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Intent main = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button2:
        newTheme = THEME_DARK;
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
        break;

    case R.id.button3:
        newTheme = THEME_LIGHT;
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case R.id.button5:
        newTheme = THEME_COLORS;
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
        break;

    case R.id.button4:
        // This button returns to the main activity without saving.
        startActivity(main);
        break;
    case R.id.button6:
        // this is the button save
        SharedPreferences settings = 
                               getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit;
        edit = settings.edit();
        edit.clear();
        edit.putInt("themeCustom", newTheme);
        edit.commit();
        startActivity(main);
        break;

    default:
        break;
        }

    }

    }
```

Comment: Do you set theme in MainActivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not saving the changes. Every time when you click on a theme change button you are just  assign a new theme value to `newTheme` tag and then you `finish()` the activity. But where you are saving the changes before finishing activity?

You should commit new changes before finishing the activity and then I think it will reflect the changes.

Comment: That is EXACTLY what was happening! i saw that before reading your post! Still gonna give you the credit for the answer!Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is because you call clear and putInt in one SharedPreferencec.Editor transaction.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#clear()

Don't call clear, only putInt

Comment: Changed it... Still the same thing.

Comment: Got it! to initialize in the mainActivity I use the same code that i use in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the int and long here.

Here newTheme is int and its storing either THEME_DARK or THEME_ILGHT and so on. But THEME_DARK and other variables are having long values i.e R.style.DarkTheme can be long or hexadecimal value.

so ultimately when you save these newTheme in sharedPref you are actually saving only 0 here.

You can check the value of newTheme variable before writing it to Shared Pref. This will clear your problem.

To Solve this you can use any other final integer value for These themes and let them save into shared pref.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you explain a little better to me? I'm new to programming.

Comment: 1.) Just Log the value of newTheme variable before saving it to shared pref.
2.) Instead Saving Theme_Dark =R.style.Theme_Dark you must use Theme_Dark=1, Theme_Light=2; and similar as all the Id provided By android are Long values and in your code you are assigning these long(long data type) values in an integer. That is why each time you are unknowingly saving O for newly created theme

Comment: Hmm i will change it! But now is working with the answer that @Vipul posted! But i maybe change it to what you said to avoid future problems.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

To save your shared preferences, you might use the following code :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = prefs.edit();
prefEditor.putInt(“themeCustom”, 0); 
prefEditor.commit();
```